# How to add a URI path to a bitmap image?

Tags: c#, uri, overlay, filepath, bitmapimage

I'm creating a bitmap image from a local image file to overlay on another bitmap, but when specify the file URI I get a `System.UriFormatException` which I cant understand as the image is stored in a folder named Images in the project which seems correct. This is how I specified the URI `new Uri("Images/boxbag.png")`. Can someone explain why I'm getting this format exception,is it a problem with the file path or the way in which I set up the URI.

This is the complete method below which should clarify things more:

```
void myKinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e) {
    using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame()) {
        if (colorFrame == null) return;
        byte[] colorData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];
        colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorData);

        KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
            PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel);

        //drawing image overlay to video feed
        var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel), 
            new Rect(new Size(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height)));
        var overlayImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/boxbag.png"));
        drawingContext.DrawImage(overlayImage, new Rect(12, 12, overlayImage.Width, overlayImage.Height));
        drawingContext.Close();
        var mergedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        mergedImage.Render(drawingVisual);

        KinectVideo.Source = mergedImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492%28v=vs.110%29.aspx:

> This constructor assumes that the string parameter references an
>   absolute URI and is equivalent to calling the Uri constructor with
>   UriKind set to Absolute. If the string parameter passed to the
>   constructor is a relative URI, this constructor will throw a
>   UriFormatException.

First, try to use an absolute path to see if everything works in principle.

If it works, you can try to find the application path, e.g. with help of `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, and construct an absolute path to the image using application path and the relative path from the application path to the image.

Something like the following:

```
string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string imageRelativePath = "...";
string imagePath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, imageRelativePath);
```

Comment: @BrianJ I added another remark. This version of constructor assumes absolute URI.

Comment: Okay I understand now, the default URI is Absolute which is why its throwing an error with a relative URI as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Uri("Images/boxbag.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

Otherwise the uri is treated as absolute and must include scheme.

Comment: Correct, but it might lead to another problem. Perhaps the path will be relative to the directory of the executable, and not to the project directory. From the question: "*the image is stored in a folder named Images in the project*".